# A button created inside code doesn't react to it's event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I just started c# and encountered an error.
I use a button `AddSquare` to add a another button `button` and then using it I want to change a textbox `ObjectName` text on that button's click. But nothing happens.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    const int UseFieldHeight = 580;
    const int UseFieldWidth = 830;
    const int UseFieldUperCoordinateX = 234;
    const int UseFieldUperCoordinateY = 101;

    Button button = new Button();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AddSquare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button.Size = new Size(50, 50);
        button.BackColor = Color.Black;
        button.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
        button.Location = new Point(UseFieldUperCoordinateX, UseFieldUperCoordinateY);
        button.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left;
        button.Visible = true;
        InitializeComponent();
        Controls.Add(button);
        button.BringToFront();
        button.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);
    }

    void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ObjectName.Text = "TEST";
    }     

}
```

Is there something else I have to do?

Comment: Why are you calling `InitializeComponent()`?

Comment: You should only call `InitializeComponent()` once, when the form loads.

Comment: Is `AddSquare_Click` ever called?

Comment: @Ralt - It's probably an event handler for a button defined in the code-behind.

Comment: It really would be good if a [mcve] were posted in the question.

Comment: First you say you get an error, but you also say nothing happens.  Which is it?  What is the error?

Comment: @Enigmativity yes thank you that fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would work if you remove the `InitializeComponent();` of your AddSquare_Click Event.